# recently uploaded style.css takes too long to "update"

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm building small blog for myself. Using hosting from Siteground and Underscores_ starter theme. I'm having problem with style.css file.

I use Cyberduck for uploads, I'm 100% sure about uploading the file into right folder, I always make sure that I'm overwriting previous one.

**Whenever I change something in style.css, I upload it to the themes folder of installed Wordpress, exactly into folder of the theme I'm editing. But when i visit the site afterwards, no visual change occurs (I'm adding @font-face), even when I check the style.css with web inspector there's no change in the file, it still is style.css from previous day.**

I don't have such problem with any other files in theme folder, for example editing header.php and adding some random placeholder text into body can be seen instantly after header.php edit and upload.

My style.css works perfectly while running it on localhost with MAMP, thus i don't think that there's problem with actual css code.

Is it normal that it takes Cca. 1 day for style.css to "update" ? By now, I can see visual changes, that I made in the style.css yesterday

Comment: Make sure you are doing a `hard reload` where the `cache` is getting wiped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To force browsers to serve the latest version of a stylesheet, you can leverage the `$version` param of `wp_enqueue_style()`. For development purposes, you can version the stylesheet URL with a UNIX timestamp. For `_s` that would be (in functions.php):

```
wp_enqueue_style( '_s-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), time() );
```

Comment: **Thank you very much, this has finally worked.** I tried everything you guessed posted. I hard-reloaded Safari( using cmd + R ), tried to install google chrome and cleared browsing data, tried different mac based computer and school computer that runs Windows. None of these worked, I was still stuck with old version of style.css, finally this wp_enequeue_style edit worked out. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing out your cache as your style.css may have been cached and therefore will not be updating instantly.

Windows:

```
CTRL + F5
```

Mac:

```
CMD + SHIFT + R
```

You can also clear your cache within the browser.

For chrome, go to

```
Menu -> Settings -> Advanced settings -> Clear browsing data
```

and tick only the option for clearing your cache for its lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your browser is caching your `style.css` file. You can force refresh all files with hard reload: hit `ctrl`+`F5` or `ctrl`+`shift`+`R` on Win or Linux or `cmd`+`shift`+`R` on Mac.

Comment: I deleted cache and reloaded website in Safari, tried to run site in Chrome while having cleared browsing data. None of these worked. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like your browser is just saving the css in your cache - clear your internet browser cache and reload the page.

info for different browsers: 
http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/

(I use chrome and simply hit ctrl and f5 every time I view my pages - there are plugins you can get which force a full refresh automatically on every page load if required.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also test your changes by accessing your website in private navigation mode.

Firefox : https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-browse-web-without-saving-info

Chrome : https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/95464?hl=en

Comment: Are you using a caching plugin such as W3 Total Cache ?

Comment: I'm not using any special plugins.